spark-connect docker client container write to parquet fails
I have have a docker container running spark connect.  Both the apache and bitmani images work.
services:

  spark-connect:
    image: apache/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-connect
    environment:
      - SPARK_NO_DAEMONIZE=yes
    ports:
      - '4040:4040'
      - "15002:15002"
    command: /opt/spark/sbin/start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1 --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Divy.cache.dir=/tmp -Divy.home=/tmp" 
    networks:
      - arr-network

  spark-connect-bitnami:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/spark:latest
    container_name: spark-connect-bitnami
    ports:
      - '4041:4040'
      - "15003:15002"
    command: start-connect-server.sh --packages org.apache.spark:spark-connect_2.12:3.5.1 
    networks:
      - arr-network


  jupyter:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_jupyter
    container_name: jupyter
    volumes:
      - ./jupyter:/home/jovyan/arr
      - ${HOME}/.config:/home/jovyan/.config
      # - ../arr-hive:/home/spark/spark-warehouse
    ports: 
      - "8888:8888"
    command: start-notebook.py --ip='*' --NotebookApp.token='' --NotebookApp.password=''
    networks:
      - arr-network


networks:
  arr-network:
    driver: bridge


Dockerfile for Jupiter
FROM quay.io/jupyter/base-notebook


RUN mamba install --yes pandas pyspark[connect] grpcio grpcio-status black jupyterlab_code_formatter && \
    mamba clean --all -f -y && \
    fix-permissions "${CONDA_DIR}" && \
    fix-permissions "/home/${NB_USER}"

USER root

ARG spark_uid=185

RUN groupadd --system --gid=${spark_uid} spark && \
    useradd --system --uid=${spark_uid} --gid=spark spark --create-home && \
    usermod -a -G users spark && \
    mkdir -m 775 /home/spark/spark-warehouse && \
    chown spark /home/spark/spark-warehouse && \
    chgrp users /home/spark/spark-warehouse && \
    echo "spark ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers 

USER spark

Connect from Jupiter works (apache or bitmani):
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pathlib import Path

# directory owned by spark (uid: 185)
save_dir = Path.home().joinpath("../spark/spark-warehouse")
with open(save_dir.joinpath("touch_this"), "w") as f:
    f.write("touched")

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("arr")
    .remote("sc://spark-connect-bitnami:15002")
    .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", save_dir)
    .enableHiveSupport()
    .getOrCreate()
)

columns = ["id","name"]
data = [(1,"Sarah"),(2,"Maria")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.show()

write() always fails
df.write.save(f'{save_dir.joinpath("test.parquet")}')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SparkConnectGrpcException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 df.write.save(f'{save_dir.joinpath("test.parquet")}')

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/readwriter.py:601, in DataFrameWriter.save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    599     self.format(format)
    600 self._write.path = path
--> 601 self._spark.client.execute_command(self._write.command(self._spark.client))

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:982, in SparkConnectClient.execute_command(self, command)
    980     req.user_context.user_id = self._user_id
    981 req.plan.command.CopyFrom(command)
--> 982 data, _, _, _, properties = self._execute_and_fetch(req)
    983 if data is not None:
    984     return (data.to_pandas(), properties)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1283, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch(self, req, self_destruct)
   1280 schema: Optional[StructType] = None
   1281 properties: Dict[str, Any] = {}
-> 1283 for response in self._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(req):
   1284     if isinstance(response, StructType):
   1285         schema = response

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1264, in SparkConnectClient._execute_and_fetch_as_iterator(self, req)
   1262                     yield from handle_response(b)
   1263 except Exception as error:
-> 1264     self._handle_error(error)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1503, in SparkConnectClient._handle_error(self, error)
   1490 """
   1491 Handle errors that occur during RPC calls.
   1492 
   (...)
   1500 Throws the appropriate internal Python exception.
   1501 """
   1502 if isinstance(error, grpc.RpcError):
-> 1503     self._handle_rpc_error(error)
   1504 elif isinstance(error, ValueError):
   1505     if "Cannot invoke RPC" in str(error) and "closed" in str(error):

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyspark/sql/connect/client/core.py:1539, in SparkConnectClient._handle_rpc_error(self, rpc_error)
   1537             info = error_details_pb2.ErrorInfo()
   1538             d.Unpack(info)
-> 1539             raise convert_exception(info, status.message) from None
   1541     raise SparkConnectGrpcException(status.message) from None
   1542 else:

SparkConnectGrpcException: (org.apache.spark.SparkException) Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 16) (6d6e48933499 executor driver): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/spark/spark-warehouse/test.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20240806134346555678479421024381_0007_m_000000_16 (exists=false, cwd=file:/opt/bitnami/spark)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:515)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:347)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:314)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:484)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:422)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:411)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetUtils$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetUtils.scala:490)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.WriteFilesExec.$anonfun$doExecuteWrite$1(WriteFiles.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:893)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:893)
    at or...

I have tried multiple things

use same UID in spark-connect container and Jupiter container are the same
set ACLs on directory structure being used
set work access

This should be simple,  in reality I want to use spark as ETL for a golang application.  However I can't even get it to work with python.
What configuration is required to make persistence work?
